# gulp tasks in sequence stop somewhere

Tags: gulp

When I run this i my visual studio:

```
// ReBuild - Clean & Build
gulp.task('rebuild', function (cb) {
    seq('clean', 'build', cb);
});
```

It stops at cleaning the files because the files are deleted but the build task seems never executed because no .ts files are build into the .js files.

Does seq really run thos tasks in sequence or parallel?

When I look at the logging output of visual studio :

```
[21:57:00] Starting 'rebuild'...
[21:57:00] Starting 'clean'...
Process terminated with code 0.
```

Rebuild is done first ... that might be the reason why I do not see the new .js files - they got deleted by my own clean task -

How can I run them in a correct sequence?

Comment: What is that `seq` function?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so that `build` must run `clean` first.

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  //clean task..
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(){
 //build task..
});
```

When the build task is called, clean will run first.

Comment: This does not work. build is never executed,Starting clean... clean seem to hang. When I run clean alone it works also the log message is the same...hm... buggy...

Comment: Can you post the entire gulp file and log? It sounds like you may have multiple problems that are contributing to your sequence not working. But it sounds like its not a sequence issue, but a task issue. Hard to say without more information.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it seems that the task `clean` is not finished at all. I am doubting that the task has something wrong.

Try [`run-sequence`](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence):

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
// ReBuild - Clean & Build
gulp.task('rebuild', function (cb) {
    runSequence('clean', 'build', cb);
});
```